# How to make this CSS switch color background change in enabled / disabled sate?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, slider

I have a CSS switch like this:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.switch { appearance: none; padding: 9px 18px; border-radius: 13px; background: radial-gradient(circle 9px, #007722 100%, transparent 100%) transparent -9px; border: 1px solid #007722; }
.switch:checked { background-position: 9px; }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="switch"></div>
```

How to make that, disabled, it stays with a transparent background, but once enabled, it has another background?

Example:

[image]

Comment: background-color: orange when :checked

Comment: Instead of enabled/disabled, do you mean checked/unchecked? Checkboxes can actually be disabled, but that doesn't appear to be what you're referring to. And A Haworth's comment would seem to do what the image shows.

Comment: @j08691 you're right: checked/unchecked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

okay so you want the switch background transparent , but once clicked it should be colorful background , try this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.switch {
  appearance: none;
  padding: 9px 18px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle 9px, #007722 100%, transparent 100%) transparent -9px;
  border: 1px solid #007722;
}

.switch:checked {
  background-position: 9px;
  background-color: orange;
  /* Add the desired background color for the enabled state */
}

.switch:disabled {
  background-color: transparent;
  /* Set the background color to transparent for the disabled state */
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* Optionally, reduce the opacity to indicate it is disabled */
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="switch"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I searched for something too complicated with `radial-gradient` whereas this simple solution works!